# iText 7 pdf signature invalid when created manually

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, digital-signature, itext7

I want to digitally sign pdf documents using iText 7. The signature is created by an external service which returns a PKCS1 signature only. I then have to create and apply  the PKCS7.

There is a good documentation for this scenario from iText: https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it7kb/examples/how-to-use-a-digital-signing-service-dss-such-as-globalsign-with-itext-7

## Sample application

I have created a sample application which signs pdf documents via local certificate. This sample application can be cloned from https://github.com/suntsu42/PdfSignSamplePkcs1. In this sample application are two different ways of creating the PKCS7. Once manually and once via a IExternalSignature(PrivateKeySignature) implementation.

For both cases, the pdf digest which must be signed is created in the same way. The only difference is the way the PKCS7 is created.

The project on github (https://github.com/suntsu42/PdfSignSamplePkcs1) is complete and self contained. In the resources folder is a private key file (pfx) used for creating the signature as well as the root certificate. In order to run the example, it should be enough to just change the value of the **resourcePath** variable to accommodate your local system.

The signature creation can be toggled by changeing the value of **createSignatureViaPlainPkcs1**

```cs
using iText.Kernel.Pdf;
using iText.Signatures;
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace PdfSignSamplePkcs1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // TODO >> Change this path based on your local system
            var resourcePath = @"c:\project\github\PdfSignSamplePkcs1\Resources\";
            var pdfToSignPath = Path.Combine(resourcePath, "test.pdf");
            var signedPdfPath = Path.Combine(resourcePath, "signedPdf.pdf");
            var privateKey = Path.Combine(resourcePath, "SignTest.pfx"); // not critical, self signed certificate
            var privateKeyPassword = "test";

            // ############
            // Change value in order to create the PKCS7
            // either manually or via Itext
            // ############
            bool createSignatureViaPlainPkcs1 = false;

            //delete signed file if it exists
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(signedPdfPath))
                System.IO.File.Delete(signedPdfPath);
            var pdfToSign = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(pdfToSignPath);
            byte[] pdfDigest = null;


            //#1 Prepare pdf for signing
            var SignatureAttributeName = $"SignatureAttributeName_{DateTime.Now:yyyyMMddTHHmmss}";
            byte[] preparedToSignPdf = null;
            using (MemoryStream input = new MemoryStream(pdfToSign))
            {
                using (var reader = new PdfReader(input))
                {
                    StampingProperties sp = new StampingProperties();
                    sp.UseAppendMode();
                    using (MemoryStream baos = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        var signer = new PdfSigner(reader, baos, sp);
                        signer.SetCertificationLevel(PdfSigner.NOT_CERTIFIED);

                        signer.SetFieldName(SignatureAttributeName);

                        DigestCalcBlankSigner external = new DigestCalcBlankSigner(PdfName.Adobe_PPKLite, PdfName.Adbe_pkcs7_detached);
                        signer.SignExternalContainer(external, 32000);

                        //get digest to be signed
                        pdfDigest = external.PdfDigest;
                        preparedToSignPdf = baos.ToArray();
                    }
                }
            }

            //#2 Create PKCS7
            SignService ss = new SignService(pdfDigest, privateKey, privateKeyPassword);
            byte[] signatureAsPkcs7 = null;
            if (createSignatureViaPlainPkcs1)
                signatureAsPkcs7 = ss.CreatePKCS7ViaPkcs1(); // >> Creates invalid pdf signature
            else
                signatureAsPkcs7 = ss.CreatePKCS7(); // Creates valid pdf signature

            //#3 apply cms(PKCS7) to prepared pdf
            ReadySignatureSigner extSigContainer = new ReadySignatureSigner(signatureAsPkcs7);
            using (MemoryStream preparedPdfStream = new MemoryStream(preparedToSignPdf))
            {
                using (var pdfReader = new PdfReader(preparedPdfStream))
                {
                    using (PdfDocument docToSign = new PdfDocument(pdfReader))
                    {
                        using (MemoryStream outStream = new MemoryStream())
                        {
                            PdfSigner.SignDeferred(docToSign, SignatureAttributeName, outStream, extSigContainer);
                            System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(signedPdfPath, outStream.ToArray());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }


}
```

### Manual creation of the pkcs7 signature

In this sample,  first create a PKCS1 signature using a local certificate. The created PKCS1 signature then is applied to the PdfPKCS7 container via **SetExternalDigest**

The pdf created in this way is invalid.

[image: invalid pdf]

```cs
        public byte[] CreatePKCS7ViaPkcs1()
        {
            //Load the certificate used for signing
            signCertificatePrivateKey = LoadCertificateFromFile();

            // create sha256 message digest
            // This is from https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it7kb/examples/how-to-use-a-digital-signing-service-dss-such-as-globalsign-with-itext-7
            // Not sure if this is required, but the created signature is invalid either way
            using (SHA256 sha256 = SHA256.Create())
            {
                Digest = sha256.ComputeHash(Digest);
            }

            //Create pkcs1 signature
            byte[] signature = null;
            using (var key = signCertificatePrivateKey.GetRSAPrivateKey())
            {
                signature = key.SignData(Digest, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256, RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);
            }

            Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate cert = DotNetUtilities.FromX509Certificate(signCertificatePrivateKey);
            PdfPKCS7 sgn = new PdfPKCS7(null, new[] { cert }, "SHA256", false);
            sgn.SetExternalDigest(signature, null, "RSA");

            //Return the complete PKCS7 CMS 
            return sgn.GetEncodedPKCS7(Digest, PdfSigner.CryptoStandard.CMS, null, null, null);
        }
```

### Create PKCS7 signature using PrivateKeySignature implementation

In this sample, the PKCS7 is created using iText PrivateKeySignature. The signature is created with the same digest and the same private key as in the other example.

The pdf created here is valid. But since this approach doesn't allow the use of an external service for creating the signature, i cannot use it.

[image]

```cs
        public byte[] CreatePKCS7ViaPkcs1()
        {
            //Load the certificate used for signing
            signCertificatePrivateKey = LoadCertificateFromFile();

            // create sha256 message digest
            // This is from https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it7kb/examples/how-to-use-a-digital-signing-service-dss-such-as-globalsign-with-itext-7
            // Not sure if this is required, but the created signature is invalid either way
            using (SHA256 sha256 = SHA256.Create())
            {
                Digest = sha256.ComputeHash(Digest);
            }

            //Create pkcs1 signature using RSA
            byte[] signature = null;
            using (var key = signCertificatePrivateKey.GetRSAPrivateKey())
            {
                signature = key.SignData(Digest, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256, RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);
            }

            Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate cert = DotNetUtilities.FromX509Certificate(signCertificatePrivateKey);
            PdfPKCS7 sgn = new PdfPKCS7(null, new[] { cert }, "SHA256", false);
            sgn.SetExternalDigest(signature, null, "RSA");

            //Return the complete PKCS7 CMS 
            return sgn.GetEncodedPKCS7(Digest, PdfSigner.CryptoStandard.CMS, null, null, null);
        }
```

## Remark (edit)

I think the reason for the problem is that i don't use GetAuthenticatedAttributeBytes for getting the hash to be signed. But i cannot use this method. The timestamp, ocsp and CLR are returned as part of the service call. Since the parameters for GetAuthenticatedAttributeBytes must be the same as when the signature is applied, i guess i cannot use this functionality.

## Question

What is the reason the signature created via RSA  is invalid in the resulting pdf?
edit: To be more specific: How can i create a valid pkcs7 container when the signature service returns PKCS1, Timestamp, Ocsp and CRL. What exactly must be signed in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One error is fairly obvious:

In `CreatePKCS7` you sign the to-be-signed attributes of the signature container (`GetAuthenticatedAttributeBytes`) which contain the document digest (`Digest`):

```c#
var sh = sgn.GetAuthenticatedAttributeBytes(Digest, PdfSigner.CryptoStandard.CMS, null, null);
byte[] extSignature = signature.Sign(sh);
```

In `CreatePKCS7ViaPkcs1` you sign the document digest (`Digest`) itself:

```c#
//Create pkcs1 signature using RSA
byte[] signature = null;
using (var key = signCertificatePrivateKey.GetRSAPrivateKey())
{
    signature = key.SignData(Digest, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256, RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);
}
```

In both cases you continue by injecting the returned signature into a `PdfPKCS7`:

```c#
sgn.SetExternalDigest(extSignature, null, signature.GetEncryptionAlgorithm());
```

and

```c#
sgn.SetExternalDigest(signature, null, "RSA");
```

respectively.

That the first variant works, is an indicator telling you that `SetExternalDigest` expects as first parameter the signature (*externally signed digest*) of the  to-be-signed attributes, not of the document digest directly.

**Thus, in `CreatePKCS7ViaPkcs1` you simply sign the wrong bytes!**

You can fix `CreatePKCS7ViaPkcs1` by (just like in `CreatePKCS7`) creating the `PdfPKCS7` instance before and receiving the to-be-signed attributes from it (using `GetAuthenticatedAttributeBytes`). You may or may not have to hash the result hereof before signing - I'm not so well-versed in .NET crypto APIs.

Comment: I think i do understand your point (I also edited the question to reflect this). My problem is that if use GetAuthenticatedAttributeBytes i need to set the OCSP and CRL. But i only the OCSP and CRL together with the signature from the signing service.

Comment: @Manuel *"But i only the OCSP and CRL together with the signature from the signing service."* - That's unfortunate: In the old ISO 32000-1 style signing (which you apparently want to do - after all you're using `PdfName.Adbe_pkcs7_detached`) OCSP and CRL are needed *before* signing as they are stored in a to-be-signed attribute, so no chance. If newer ISO 32000-2 style signing structures are ok, too, you can add OCSP and CRL data in a separate, second step. Either way, you should make your code work without OCSP and CRLs first.

Comment: @Manuel By the way, there are some signing services that return a complete CMS container including CRLs and/or OCSP responses in signed attributes for use in PDFs. IIRC the SwissCom used to operate such a service.

Comment: In case the service is implement as ISO 32000-2 must it return a complete PKCS7 container, or should it also work when all parts are returned separately?

Comment: Another side note: I use Adbe_pkcs7_detached because thats what i've found in the documentation and i thought this is the correct one.

Comment: @Manuel First of all, whether or not you can use the PAdES/ISO 32000-2 style revocation information, depends on your use case, you have to check the requirements. If you can use them, you simply as a first step create a signature *without* any embedded revocation information, probably setting a different subfilter, and in a second step append the revocation information to the PDF as defined in PAdES or ISO 32000-2. Thus, this works fine with separately returned information.

Comment: @Manuel I don't know, though, according to which validation rules your signatures need to be verifiable. E.g. a service like the one you use most likely is going to generate issues if validation shall follow ETSI rules and eIDAS regulations.

Comment: The service i use is actually implemented according to ISO 32000-1. I now create the ocsp information myself based on the public key used for signing. This then creates a valid LTV Enabled information. Thanks for your help